# google sheets Detect change made to sheet name

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am displaying all sheet names in a certain sheet. I want those sheet names to be updated with every update to a sheet name.

I tried looking for such events but there don't seem to be any. Any solutions to this problem?

Comment: use an onEdit trigger and watch that particular range for edits.

Comment: I don't mean edits made to the names entered in the cells. I mean actual sheet names.

Comment: "sheet names to be updated with every update to a sheet name" --> doesn't that mean : when you change (edit) a sheet name in the cell, the name of the sheet/tab changes ?

Comment: I mean the reverse of what you said: when you change the name of the sheet/tab, the sheet name in the cell changes.

Answer (score -1):

@JPV you're correct! everytime [`onEdit()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit) is triggered, it returns an [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) `(e)` that gives you some valuable information about what is happening. It passess the function event object as an argument typically called `e`. The event object contains information about the context that caused the trigger to fire. Google added an `On Change` event that detects insertion/deletion along with other things.

The following are the instructions detailing how to add a trigger to your script that may have function called `on change` event:

To run a script when a particular action is performed:

- Open or a create a new Spreadsheet.
- Click the **Unsaved Spreadsheet** dialog box and change the name.
- Choose **Tools > Script Editor** and write the function you want to run.
- Choose **Resources > Current project's triggers.** You see a panel with the message** No triggers set up. Click here to add one now**.
- Click the link.
- Under **Run**, select the function you want executed by the trigger.
- Under **Events**, select *From Spreadsheet*.
- From the next drop-down list, select **On open, On edit, or On form submit**.
- Click **Save**.